# How to adjust server's time zone in Apache using wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have developed my website in wordpress and it's `error_log`uses the default server time zone, but i want it to use my timezone which is `Asia/Kuwait`.

How to adjust/change the server to use my region's time zone.I'm using Wordpress and i have no access to the php.ini

Comment: are you using any php framework ? please mention if so .. else follow this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: Yes i am using wordpress

Comment: hope this may help you http://help.coschedule.com/hc/en-us/articles/214455448-How-To-Change-Your-WordPress-Timezone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for: `date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier )`

You can also set this in your php.ini config.

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = Europe/Berlin
```

Comment: I have no access to the php.ini. i will try the `date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier )`

Comment: @MohamedOmar did you check this http://help.coschedule.com/hc/en-us/articles/214455448-How-To-Change-Your-WordPress-Timezone ?

Comment: Yes but it worked using the `date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier )`

Comment: @MohamedOmar thats great but if in future you want it dynamic then ? we should try to execute this thing from admin side only so that in future it will work smoothly if required as we/someone else would not need to touch code at that time.

Comment: I already had my admin settings set to `UTC+3` which is my timezone but the sever was using it default time zone

Comment: @MohamedOmar i c.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129346/discussion-between-mittul-at-technobrave-and-mohamed-omar).

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in your php.ini file by changing the value of `date.timezone`

```
date.timezone = Asia/Kuwait
```

[This](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php/setting-the-timezone-for-php-in-the-phpini-file) link explains how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

use below code to set your default time zone set.

paste this code in index.php file

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); ?>
```

set your timezone using wp-admin dashboard.
General Settings->Timezone

Answer (score 0):

Use this reference :

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Good luck.